# How to find number between of NSArray Of NSDictionary With Two Different Keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

### Here's my code snippet for this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrTableData = [NSMutableArray new];

[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:700], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:760]}];

[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:760], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:820]}];

[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:820], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:940]}];

[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:940], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:990]}];
```

I want find `number == 800` using `NSPredicate` Only.

### Case: 1

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:940];

NSPredicate *subQuery1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"from >= %@ OR to < %@",number,number];

NSArray *filteredArray = [arrTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:subQuery1];
```

- I don't like use to **loop** and **enumerateObjectsUsingBlock**

Comment: what the output you expect

Comment: @{@"from":760, @"to":820}

Comment: why you are not tried `@" to < %@"`

Comment: Means what? do you want to filter 'from >= 940' OR 'to < 940' and the result will be `{@"from":940, @"to":990}` ?? is that what you need?

Comment: if you are used this `>=` you get this one also `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:940], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:990]`

Comment: If i am tried to < 800 so i am getting top 1 array of dictionary. like as [{@"from":700, @"to":760}] but i want to get [{@"from":760, @"to":820}]

Comment: have you tried @SudhirChovatiya  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46461939/4061501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the other way round.

The predicate must be **greater than or equal `from` AND less than `to`**

```
NSNumber *number = @800.0;
NSPredicate *subQuery1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"from <= %@ AND to > %@", number, number];
```

or

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ >= from AND %@ < to", number, number];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
NSMutableArray *arrTableData = [NSMutableArray new];

[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:700], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:760]}];

[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:760], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:820]}];

[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:820], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:940]}];

[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:940], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:990]}];

NSLog(@"%@",arrTableData);

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"from >= 800"];

NSArray  *filterdArray = [[arrTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"filter arr : %@",filterdArray);
```

It will give array of dictionaries having from is greater or equal to 800!

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"from >= 800"]; 
to get
 [arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:820], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:940]}];

'[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:940], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:990]}];'

 but i want to get only 

'[arrTableData addObject:@{@"from":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:760], @"to":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:820]}];'

Comment: ? What you what as output ?  do you want from greater than 800 ? or to greater than 800 ? or do you want that both key is equal to 800 ? what is your exact need ? what is your range ? do you want fix number `760 and 820` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *resultArray = [arrTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(from >= %@) OR (to < %@)", @800,@800]];
```

To filter `to < 800`

```
NSArray *resultArray2 = [arrTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(from < %@)", @800]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't add anything to the previous answers, but you really should consider modernising our Objective-C code. The code in your question could be simplified to…

```
NSMutableArray *arrTableData = [NSMutableArray new];
[arrTableData addObjectsFromArray: @[@{@"from":@700.0, @"to":@760.0},
                                     @{@"from":@760.0, @"to":@820.0},
                                     @{@"from":@820.0, @"to":@940.0},
                                     @{@"from":@940.0, @"to":@990.0}]];
```

You can do this easily by selecting Edit -> Convert -> To Modern Objective-C Syntax…

[image]